# Expo Constants package error relating to Expo Camera, relating to SDK 34

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a message which I can't remove when running my application

> The following APIs have moved to separate packages and importing them
>   from the "expo" package is deprecated: Constants.
>
> Add correct versions of these packages to your project using:
>
> `expo install expo-constants`
>
> If "install" is not recognized as an expo command, update your
>   expo-cli installation.
>
> Change your imports so they use specific packages instead of the
>   "expo" package:
>
> `import { Constants } from 'expo' -> import Constants from
>   'expo-constants'`

I am installed the necessary package as directed, but still getting this error while trying to use the camera package in expo

below is my camera component code

Camera.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text,
Alert, Modal, } from 'react-native';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { Constants } from 'expo-constants';
import { Entypo, MaterialIcons, MaterialCommunityIcons,
  SimpleLineIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Camera extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hasCameraPermission: null,
      type: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
      picture: null
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted' });
  }

  takePicture = async () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      console.log('');

      const photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync({ base64: true });

      this.setState({
        foo: Math.random()
      });

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('image', photo.base64);
      formData.append('type', 'base64');

      this.setState({
        picture: photo.uri,
        isCameraVisible: false
      });
    }
  };

  openCamera = () => {
    const { hasCameraPermission } = this.state;
    if (!hasCameraPermission) {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'No access to camera');
    } else {
      this.setState({ isCameraVisible: true });
    }
  };

  closeCamera = () => {
    this.setState({
      isCameraVisible: false
    });
  };

  flipCamera = () => {
    this.setState({
      type: this.state.type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
        ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
        : Camera.Constants.Type.back,
    });
  };

}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried importing Constants in the following way `import Constants from 'expo-constants';` ? Because in your code you are doing the following `import { Constants } from 'expo-constants';`

Comment: Also your component is called `Camera` which you are importing from `expo-camera`. This is probably causing confusion, perhaps you should change your component to something like `class MyCamera extends Component { ... }`

Comment: thanks, I imported it wrong

Answer (score 0):

The import needs to be corrected.
Constants and Camera imports in the code are incorrect.

Try changing Constants "**without the curly braces**"
It should work then

Comment: Please provide more information for further detail.